# How to Automate Terminal Commands

Tags: terminal

What programming language has the capability to automatically execute terminal commands?

Say I want to scan a Wifi network for IP addresses using `arp -a` and print those IP addresses to the screen?

What programming language is best equipped to do this? Python? Ruby?

Comment: almost every language can do it. So just google it out for the language you are using in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all modern programming languages has the capability to execute terminal commands (in python you can use the `os` or `subprocess` modules).

But for your project I would be easier if you use bash script http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html